# Vertica role grant not working

Tags: sql, vertica

I am trying to setup a new role for making the access rights granting easier. I was wondering if there is an easier way to give select on all tables (newly created tables should be accessible automatically) under a schema to selected users. I ran following queries for the same. But still my user is not able to access the specific table.

```
CREATE ROLE myrole;

GRANT SELECT ON myschema.mytable TO myrole;

GRANT usage ON schema myschema TO myrole;

CREATE USER mytest1 identified BY '***';

GRANT myrole TO mytest1;
```

After this, when I login with mytest1 user and trying to run select on myschema.mytable it is asking me to grant usage on schema to user. After I grant usage on schema to user directly it is failing with permission denied for that table.

Please help with the same. I am running on vertica 5.0

**Update:**
I find that u also have to make that role default or explicitely set that role as default for user session for making the role's effect take place.

```
ALTER USER mytest1 DEFAULT ROLE myrole;
```

But still, my another question of how to make all tables under a schema accessible to specific users remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Vertica **SQL Reference Manual.pdf** (page 725) (doc version 5.0 - for page numbers)

> ```
> GRANT (Schema)
> ...
> USAGE
> Allows the user  access to the objects contained  within the 
> schema. This allows the user to look up objects within the 
> schema. Note that the user must also be granted access to the
> individual objects. See the GRANT TABLE (page 727) ... .
> ```

The `the user must also be granted access to the individual objects` means that you need to also `GRANT table`.

The two I use is `GRANT SELECT` and `GRANT REFERENCES` which allows the user to run queries and join (reference) tables in the query.

Example:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE [schema].[Table1] TO myUser;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE [schema].[Table2] TO myUser;
GRANT REFERENCES ON TABLE [schema].[Table1] TO myUser;
GRANT REFERENCES ON TABLE [schema].[Table2] TO myUser;
...
```

6.0 doc reference `GRANT SCHEMA` (page 808) and `GRANT TABLE` (page 813).